# Remap Super/Windows Start Button on Keyboard?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Is it possible to remap the Super (Windows Start) button to open All Applications instead of the Activities Overview?

I installed Tweaks to do a few other things but haven't seen anything about mapping the Super Key directly and was wondering how it is possible in GNOME and if there was a UI I'm overlooking or if I should be looking for a terminal command?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071388/how-to-make-the-left-super-key-open-show-applications-menu-as-a-shortcut though you should know that A it is possible but B kinda useless because what do you do generally on windows after hitting Super? start typing the name of the app you want, right? Which works exactly the same on ubuntu, if you start typing you'll have the list of apps show up. Lastly if you type `Super`+`A` you'll have what you want.

Comment: @tatsu B is quite useful as a generic approach: you could, that way, bind your custom launcher (e.g. Synapse, Albert) to the Super key, or have it do anything else you want.

Comment: Thanks all. I think between the solutions there like ksuperkey I'll be good to go. Guess I didn't search the right terms so thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I do agree it's useful to be able to map the Super key to anything.